# How to make a query to find project which is having max number of tickets?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I made a query but its not working:

```sql
SELECT project_fk,
       COUNT(*) as tickets
FROM ticket_details
where project_fk = MAX(tickets)
```

Here I am fetching data from ticket_details table where project_fk is a foreign key

I am using mariadb same as mysql

Comment: If you are using MySQL please don't tag SQL Server, it's a completely different RDBMS.

Comment: This is working but my question is I want to fetch a project which is having max number of tickets your query is giving me whole ticket count

Comment: I think you meant to put that common on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65123363/2029983) , Utkarsh.

Comment: Yes sir I am also making procedure of this query and I also need to add another query like   Number of tickets registered and average closing time - project wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT project_fk, COUNT(*) as tickets 
FROM ticket_details 
GROUP BY project_fk 
ORDER BY 2 DESC LIMIT 1
```

If two or more projects have the same maximal amount of rows then only one will be returned.